# Registry change to set windows 10 desktop icons sort by type

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

Im looking for a way to change the sort style of windows 10 to *by item type* in the registry. Found a lot of right click solutions but having to setup dozens of computers it would be a nightmare.

What I have tried so far:

One of the other tasks I had to do was setting desktop icon view to *Auto arrange icons* and *align icons to grid*. This lead me to the registry location of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`. Setting the `FFlags` value allowed me to tweak those settings. I also see a *Sort* value in the same location. However it doesn't appear to be changing when I right click desktop, then sort -> by file type.

Does anyone know which registry key reflects the sort style? Or perhaps a better way to do this all together?